# How to use a shared resource for localization in .net core 2 in controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, asp.net-core-localization

I'm new to .net core development after years of working in .net framework on mostly webform applications.

I'm trying to localize a new project and looking at options determined for this particular use that a shared resource would be the most maintainable solution long term and followed this example: https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

This appears to work great for adding the localized data in the view but I am struggling to be able to do so in the controller such as returning a localized error when something is caught server side and a custom message would be returned.

In my controller's I added

```
private readonly LocService _SharedLocalizer;
```

Within a view's method in the controller if I try and add

```
ViewBag.localizedmessage = _SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("message")
```

I get a null error on accessing the page on this line.

If I create a new instance within the view's method I am not sure what to provide as the argument value for the IStringLocalizerFactory.

```
_SharedLocalizer = new LocService();
```

What is the piece I am missing or how do I go about properly accessing the shared resource in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly LocService _SharedLocalizer;
        public YourController(LocService localizer)
        {
            _SharedLocalizer = localizer;
        }
}
```